# Llama event on manual profile change

Tags: automation, llama

Can I call an event in Llama on manual profile change?

E.g. Change profile to Develop = when connected to laptop disable screen lock, always on etc.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot set up an event to trigger when a Llama profile has changed. Changing a Llama profile is only an `action`, and unfortunately isn't available as a `condition`.

There also isn't a condition for `Connected to Computer`. But there is a `Charging or Unplugged` condition that you can use to trigger other events. If you are fine with the more broad event of activating a profile when the phone is plugged in (to anything), that's doable.